# Align final line in a String

Tags: java, android

I want to set a String on a TextView and I want to right align the final line, like this

```
"Rose are red, Violets are blue..

                              Me"
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: try this `TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<div align=\"left\">Rose are red, Violets are blue..
</div><div align=\"right\">Me</div>"`

Comment: Worked! Please give as an answer so I can vote up for you! Thx man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3); 
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<div align=\"left\">Rose are red, Violets are blue.. </div><div align=\"right\">Me</div>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea...

Create 2 TextViews. The first TextView will be the text and the second will be the last line of the text. Make the second TextView below the first TextView and align the second TextView to the right.

In your code, split the String (or whatever method you want to use) and set the text to the TextViews accordingly...

I can't go into any more detail since you haven't provided information on how the text is constructed. Please be more detailed. More details, the better.